# In Bezique, what's the point of dealing the cards 3-2-3?

Tags: bezique

I'm trying to learn how to play the card game Bezique, and I'm puzzled by the rule that says the cards are dealt face-down in a 3, 2, 3 pattern.  Apparently the dealer deals three cards to each player, then two to each player, then three again to each player, for a total of eight each.

The rules I've found aren't very explicit about this, but it seems like the players pick up and look at their cards after the deal.  So why are the cards dealt like this?  What difference does it make to the game?

Comment: There are other games in which cards are dealt that way.

Comment: @Chenmunka I believe you.  I just ran across one a few minutes ago.  But...what's the point of dealing the cards that way?

Comment: Maybe making it harder to cheat by fake shuffle/ cutting cards. Or easier for counting how many cards are dealt (counting to 3 is easier visually than to 8 or if the person can't count to 8 at all). Or because it was always done like that

Answer (score -2):

*This is speculation by me, though I think it’s the most likely explanation.*

Many traditional card games have rules like this. I think they’re a trade-off between cheat-prevention, superstition, and speed of dealing.

After shuffling and cutting, many people feel like certain cards are “theirs”, so you want to get your cards and not somebody else’s. The easiest way of achieving this is by dealing cards one at a time.  But when dealing many cards, this takes too much time.

The solution is to deal multiple cards at once (and two to four cards each time is common as it’s relatively easy to reliably take this many cards from the top of the deck). However, to keep the “I want my cards” people satisfied, the order of dealing must still be fixed, so it’s clear what your cards are. This avoids discussions about not receiving “the correct cards” because the dealer did it wrong. (It can also help with cheating in case of marked cards, though I don’t think this effect is very strong.)

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with people wanting to get their cards and that certain cards are "theirs"

Comment: I think it absolute has to do with this. I imagine players sitting around the table for a somewhat serious game (maybe even some money on the line), and someone loses. They (want to) think that their hand was bad, so they complain that the dealer dealt the cards weirdly. “You should have dealt them one by one (then I would have gotten a better hand)!” To avoid discussions like this, you codify the dealing, and as dealing one-by-one is too slow, you deal multiple cards at once. If you want to deal 8 cards that way, 3-2-3 is reasonable, though the important part is to have a fixed rule at all.

Comment: You will need something to back that up besides thinking that it does as I have never heard of that in all the time I have played cards. Most games I know of expect the cards to be delt out one at a time and don't have an issue with dealing speed.

Comment: I agree that it’s speculative, though I cannot really see another explanation.  There are quite a few games with these kinds of rules. (Skat and Doppelkopf come to my mind immediately, and I think Bezique stems from the same tradition.) All of them are old enough that it’s probably impossible to really figure out where the rules originated, but there is no gameplay reason dealing could not proceed in other ways. (I clarified the speculativeness of my answer a bit.)

Comment: This site isn't looking for speculative answers rather it wants fact based answers. And as I have stated I have never heard of that reasoning for making rules for dealing more cards at once. Everything I have read is the amount of cards dealt at once impacts the randomness of card distribution, not speed of dealing. And honestly dealing out 8 cards to 2 players is going to take about the same amount of time dealing them one at a time versus 3-2-3 due to the low number of cards/players and having to count them out while dealing.

Comment: Without trying to make an argument in favor of this answer, I'll mention that the concept of people thinking they own certain cards is a thing at Blackjack tables at times, where people will get unhappy about the player ahead of them hit when according to Basic Strategy, the should have stood, meaning the card the first player hit was the card the second player would have gotten. Of course, this is not a rational argument, as there is no expectation of adherance to Basic Strategy in the rules or etiquette of Blackjack.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I will update my comment and say I have heard of it in blackjack and games like that when players have a different amount of cards that they ask for but not in games that everyone is dealt a set number of cards.

Comment: I don’t think we will get anything better than speculation for this particular question, unless someone can dig up a diary by the people who created this particular rule in Bezique (or one of its predecessors).

Comment: Certainly if you're getting eight cards, it does make it easier to see at a glance whether you have the right number of cards if they're dealt 3-2-3 instead of 8 in one clump.